# many button in windows form with same event, in event i need name of button that selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i have 46 button in form and all of them to same work just diffrent in value.
mean `button1` plus 1 to sum , `button2` plus 2 to sum ...
is there a way to understand which one of buttons are pressed to get it `Text`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call a function with this button TEXt
        // if button 1 selected -> func("1")
        // if button 2 selected -> func("2")
    }
```

is there any way do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sender` returns your button.So you can get the button like

```
Button clicked = (Button)sender;
```

In specifying the buttons, you can check that sender button's `Text` or you can give them `Tag` and check them. You said text, so

```
Button clicked = (Button)sender;
func(clicked?.Text);
```

should work.

Comment: Buttons only have a `Text` property, but not a `Content` property in WinForms. Other than that, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: i got answer from this post , and will marked as answer as it possible.

Comment: Oh i missed the Forms part and thought that was a WPF. Editing rn.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

    if (clickedButton != null)
    {
        button.Name....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution is to create for each button  an event_click (so button1_Click, button2_Click etc. Better to name the buttons appropriate.

Than from within each event handler, call the same function to add the number to the sum e.g.:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add(1);
} 

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add(2);
} 

// Same for other event handlers.

private void add(int number)
{
   sum += number;
}
```

Comment: i know this but it cause 46 function is there any way to do all in one?

Comment: I don't know by head, but what I normally do in such situation, is put a breakpoint within the event, start the debugger, and check how sender looks like internally; I'm sure there is some clue which button is selected. (according to other answers the sender IS the button).

Answer (score 0):

You can link all your event handlers and then use the `Name` property to decide which button was clicked.

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.button2.Click += this.button1_Click;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = sender as Button;

            switch(btn.Name.ToLower())
            {
                case "button1":
                    MessageBox.Show("Add 1");
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    MessageBox.Show("Add 2");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Button not found");
                    break;
            }
        }
```